# Does anybody know Python open souce web applications that use sqlite library?

Tags: python, open-source, python-3.x

I need to find this kind of open source web applications written in Python that use sqlite library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documents of [SQLLite](http://www.sqlite.org/about.html) `SQLite is an embedded SQL database engine. Unlike most other SQL databases, SQLite does not have a separate server process. SQLite reads and writes directly to ordinary disk files.` SQLLite will use the file system to store the data. You can give the path where you have to store the data.

Python provide many web framework like [Django](https://djangoproject.com/), [Plone](http://plone.org/), [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)...

All framework mention in http://www.wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks

Answer (score 1):

See [Web2py](http://web2py.com/). It uses SQLite as the default backend.